# Pylons - url.current() incorrect, for '/test' shows '/test/test'?

Tags: python, url-routing, pylons

I've got a pylons setup, using flup with nginx, and `url.current()` always returns totally wrong.

I have a route:

```
map.connect('testpage', '/test', controller='Main', action='test')
```

And in that controller, I do url.current() and I get `/test/test' instead of '/test'.  I've tried changing`SCRIPT_NAME` as various posts about using uwsgi suggest, but it makes no difference here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you have `map` defined with a `.connect` method? `map` is the name of a python builtin.

Comment: it's a routes.Mapper object, this is how you map URLs to handlers in Pylons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it looks like I solved this.  Apparently you have to set SCRIPT_NAME to '' AND restart the Pylons application, which I apparently hadn't tried before.

So if anyone else has this problem - restart Pylons :)

Comment: One way to improve this is to launch your application during development like this: paster serve --reload -v config.ini

This will automatically reload the pylons app each time you make a change and save it anywhere in the Pylons application.

Answer (score 0):

in nginx i do

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

Comment: Right, but as I said, that's what I was doing and it wasn't actually changing things until I restarted the Pylons app.