# help with pylons routes url_for~

Tags: python, routes, pylons

view-source:http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/post/edit/2 :

```
<form action="/admin/post/update_post/2" method="post">
```

view-source:http://xxx.com/admin/post/edit/2

```
<form action="/admin/post/edit/2/admin/post/update_post/2" method="post">
```

something was diffent between server url code and localhost serve with the same code :

```
${form(url(controller='admin/post', action='update_post', id=request.urlvars['id']), method='post')}
```

both of them using pylons 1.0 and server online run with nginx~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the url should start with a /. Also, you've specified a controller of 'admin/post' and I'm thinking that is probably supposed to be either or.

Give this a try

```
url('/admin/post/edit/' + request.urlvars['id'])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842692/pylons-url-current-incorrect-for-test-shows-test-test/4965716#4965716